# Rest assured prettyprint adds decimals to output

Tags: rest-assured

I have a json string where I have fields like this `"cost": 5`. In my rest assured code, I print it with:

```
response.body().prettyPrint();
```

OR

```
response.body().jsonPath().prettyPrint();
```

The 5 appears as 5.0. Any idea why this happens and how to fix it ?

On the other hand, this prints my json without the decimals:

```
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.body().asString());
    System.out.println(json.toString(2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to fix this by using prettyPrint in RestAssured. RestAssured simply delegates to this Groovy class, which does not give the possibility to change it.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html

There is 0 difference (in javascript, and thus json) between 5 and 5.0

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type

Comment: What is the correct value for the number then ? Postman shows it as integer in pretty view, but shows it as double in raw view.

Comment: It's the same value, represented 2 different ways.